# Manual analysis to determine if the path taken in the graph is the shortest path

Tags: graph, path-finding

Pathfinding algorithms such as A* 100% guarantees the shortest path. But can we can manually analyze if a given path in the graph is the shortest path?

Suppose that we have this weighted graph
[Weighted Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRJVw.png)

Let's say that our starting node is NODE 1 and we want to go to NODE 2. The path that we took is node 1 -> node 2. Obviously this is the shortest path. How can we manually prove or determine whether this path is the shortest route without any computers?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

One can go with `Dijkstra` Algorithm to find the shortest path.